# Question about google multilanguage sitemap.xml

Tags: sitemap

I'm writing a script to maintain sitemaps, but I don't understand this.

Here's a screenshot from Google Sitemap:
[image]

Is it acceptable to use the Aramaic (am) language code in the 'loc' attribute, and 'x-default' as the 'href' value in the 'xhtml' tag?

This approach would address several issues in script design, making it more flexible (allowing the placement of 'hreflang' links in 'loc' without requiring 'x-default').

I assume that if Google implements something, it's likely to be effective. However, before writing any code, I'd like to inquire if anyone has any knowledge or definitive insights on this matter. Despite searching extensively today, I haven't found a conclusive answer.

Comment: I thought Aramaic was a dead language.  You don't actually have a version of your site in that language, do you?